# Как пройти по списку списков "улиткой" от краев к центру, все элементы вывести в список

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def snail(snail_map):
    f=lambda m:m and m.pop(0)+f([list(x)for x in zip(*m)][::-1])

    return f

array = [[1,2,3],
         [4,5,6],
         [7,8,9]]
#expected = [1,2,3,6,9,8,7,4,5]
```

Comment: а то это только адрес выводит

Comment: А если отставить эти лямбды и зипы, и просто циклами в нужном порядке обойти?

Comment: да конечно пробую

Comment: Здесь таких вопросов изрядно есть - искали?

Comment: искал но конкретно пока не нашел

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Цель этого задания - освоить циклы и реализовать логику изменения движения.

Возможный вариант решения - будем рассматривать направление и количество шагов в этом направлении. Видим, что для матрицы размером n:

```
 делается n шагов
 направление меняется на 90 градусов
 делается n-1 шагов
 направление меняется на 90 градусов
 делается n-1 шагов
 направление меняется на 90 градусов
 делается n-2 шагов
 направление меняется на 90 градусов
 делается n-2 шагов
```

и так далее.

Количество шагов повторяется дважды, поэтому можно завести переменную `size2=2*n` и рассчитывать количество шагов как половину от текущего size2 с использованием целочисленного деления.

После каждого прохода меняется направление. Можно записать последовательность направлений `[0,1,0,-1]` и брать оттуда очередное направление (по иксу сдвинуто относительно игрека), а можно просто поворачивать вектор направления

```
n = 5
a = [[(10*y+x) for x in range(n)] for y in range(n)]
print(a)
x = -1
y = 0
dx = 1  #начальное направление
dy = 0   
cc = 0  #для поворота 
ss = 1
size2 = 2*n
while size2:
    for i in range(size2 // 2):
        y += dy
        x += dx
        print(a[y][x], end = ',')
    size2 -= 1
    t = dx * cc - dy * ss
    dy = dx * ss + dx * cc
    dx = t

 [[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4], 
  [10, 11, 12, 13, 14], 
  [20, 21, 22, 23, 24], 
  [30, 31, 32, 33, 34], 
  [40, 41, 42, 43, 44]]

 0,1,2,3,4,14,24,34,44,43,42,41,40,30,20,10,11,12,13,23,33,32,31,21,22,
```

Вариант с направлением из списка:

```
 ds = [0, 1, 0, -1]
 dx = ds[1]
 dy = ds[0]
 ...
 dy = ds[(2*n-size2)%4]
 dx = ds[(2*n-size2 + 1)%4]
```

Comment: рабочий с небольшими правками

Comment: Какими правками?